# What to do with equipment for old PowerBook 5300c and other Equipment?

Tags: power-mac

I found a box with equipment (PC Cards, cables, etc.) from my old PowerBook 5300c and I wonder what to do with it.

Here in central Europe it seemed that nobody needs something like that.

Are there people somewhere else in the world who still use 68k PowerMacs and would have any use for such things?
I'd happily donate the parts if I knew that they are useful for somebody...

**remark:** this question is not *not* meant as a small ad, but I'd like to know if there are maybe charitable societies which would distribute such technical equipment to people who benefit from it.

Comment: I would say there are some people out there still using old 68K macs for something, maybe some business using it to print invoices on a dot matrix printer, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like eBay or classified ads, and then donation and or recycling after that if no one wants the stuff.

Comment: hm, but donation to whom?

Comment: Not really sure for Europe, but in the States I would say something like GoodWill (http://www.goodwill.org/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: FYI, Also your best is something like eBay, since you have very specific parts, and not the whole computer. So someone searching for those old parts are more likely to find them on eBay. And heck you might have something worth more than you thought too.